# Corporation Stake Problem

Tags: java, recursion

I've just stumbled upon this problem on the net. It kind of goes something like this.

There are corporations that have stakes in other corporations. And I would like to find out if one company owns another company.

So, the problem is this, if company 1 owns more than 75% of company 2, he automatically owns it. And another twist is that if company 1 owns more than 75% of company 3 that owns more than 75% of company 2, then company 1 owns company 2.

Here's a clearer example:

```
Company 1 owns 50% of Company 2
Company 1 owns 75% of Company 3
Company 3 owns 25% of Company 2

Therefore, Company 1 owns Company 2
```

I think it will involve recursion, splitting the ownership process by company. However, I can't figure out how to implement this. Thank you very much for your help!

*Update : Sorry for not properly defining the problem. The problem consists of records, containing three pieces of data, as seen above, and the problem is to find out if a certain company owns another (eg does company 1 own company 2?).

So I'm planning to store each ownership value to the owner (for direct ownership) and reduce the ownership value of indirect owners (if own > 75%, then replace w/ next owner) until it reaches the base. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: You might want to clarify things by posting your exact homework assignment and then letting us know what you've tried so far.

Comment: This could be an interesting problem, but you haven't really defined the problem yet. You have defined the notion of "ownership". For example, you might say something like "Given a set of companies `C1,C2,...,CN`, and a set of ownership triples `(a,b,x)` denoting that `a` owns `x` percent of `b`, for each company, produce a list of all companies that it owns. As it is, I don't know what a solution to the problem looks like.

Comment: If you do implement this make sure you do plenty of tests with known graph in human proportions.  Also I'd be curious to see how it turned out, if you could provide updates or comments with your results I would greatly appreciate and would be glad to help in fixing problems you could find.  Thanks for the question that was a lot of fun !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make no assumption on the list, how long it can be and how many companies are involved.  I also make no assumption that all companies are linked.  It is possible the list can form many distinct ownership graph.  I also assume it is possible for scenarios allowing some form of mutual ownership (A own 75% of B and B own 75% of A, strange situation I'll admit but mathematically there is nothing preventing this from happening)

A Brute Force algorithm to solve absolute ownership could be done this way :

First pass - Determine all associations of a company with other companies.

```
Let C be the company of interest
Let A be the list of companies C has associations with.
Let Astar be a list of companies not already visited, initially containing C.
Let dist be the distance of companies from C, initially set to 0.

While Astar is not empty
    Let X be the first in Astart, remove X from Astar
    Add X to A
    dist++
    For each company Y that X has stakes in
        if Y is not in Astar, 
            Set Y.dist = dist
            Add Y to Astar
```

Now we have a list (A) of companies that C can potentially own, all other companies in the original list can be ignored.

now let's calculate the actual ownership.  Here we attempt to calculate the actual stakes C has in all other companies.  If C owns 50% of X and X owns 50% of Y then C owns 25% of Y.  To take into account the 75% rule, if at any point a company has 70% or more stakes in another we automatically convert the 75% into 100%.

```
Let X[] be an array containing the stakes X has in all other companies within A, initially set to 0

For each company in A
   Let X be the company the furthest away from C not already visited in A.
   Mark X as visited.
   For each edge E leading away from X to company Y
       if the Y is marked visited in A
           For each edge F leading away from Y to company Z
               Set X[Z] = F * E   
               If X[Z] >= 75%
                   Set F = 100%
                   remove visited mark on X
       else
           For each company W that Y has stakes in
              Set X[W] = Y[W] * E
```

This will perform a sort of backtracking algorithm that will re-evaluate stakes when ownership is established.  At the end you should have the array C[] with all the net stakes C has in all other companies. If any are above 75% then C owns it.

This is a very brute algorithm, it would be preferable to merge the two passes into one to make it a more elegant solution though at this point I prefer getting proof of something that works rather than something that looks or performs good.  I have not tried it, only ran it mentally so I could be very wrong.  However I think it would cover the mutual ownership cycles.  However to see the mutual ownership you would have to repeat the procedure replacing C for every company in the list.  Then you would have a complete picture of ownership directly visible from each company.

--- EDIT ---

I hope I did not misunderstand here, the question is indeed hard to fully grasp.  If we have a large set of companies and ownership is defined in triplets then you could do as below by letting the list be all the triplets bundled together.  This would create a larger graph but solving one graph is much easier than solving a set of interdependent graphs

Comment: I did not actually take into account the ownership, when .50 * .50 = .25, but thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 2):

I think the following works, but I didn't thoroughly test it. Frankly I'm not sure I even understand your requirements.

Construct a directed graph based on the input. Each named company becomes a vertex. Each edge represents an ownership relationship between companies and has a weight equal to the ownership percentage.

To determine which companies are owned by a specific company, use the following pseudocode:

```
Let company C be the company of interest
Let T be a table of all companies and their total ownership by company C
Let S be the set of companies completely owned by C, initially containing only C itself

While S is not empty:
    Choose an unvisited company X from S
    Mark X as visited
    For each edge leading away from X to another company Y:
        Add the edge's weight to T[Y]
        If T[Y] >= 75, add Y to S
```

Comment: This is incomplete, it will not cover cycles within the graph that are more than 3 levels deep.  It is possible that a company already ownership be established indirectly through ownership of multiple subsidiaries of multiple companies that happen to invest in a common company.  In this case, each individual subsidiary could not claim ownership but owning enough of them would indirectly make you owner of that other company.  Because the graph can contain cycles the algorithm must contain some form or recursion.  Disclaimer, I have not done graph algorithm in a looooong time !! :-)  this is fun